# Button Ban Command

Tags: discord, discord.js

Currently I'm trying to make a Ban Command which has Buttons to determine if a User should be banned or not. However, it now sets the Author and User as 'undefined' even though a User has been provided.

(Side Note, there's no Error showing up in the Console)

[image: Here's what it currently looks like]

Since the Code is pretty big, I decided to make a hastebin. Link: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/enolimecir.js

Comment: If the code is too big, make it smaller. See [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at your code and as you can see at your line 26 - 31 (.setDescription), thats where the undefined came from.

```js
.setDescription(`**User:** ${user.user.mention}\n**Moderator:** ${message.author.mention}\n**Reason:** ${reason}`)
```

`user.user.mention` will not work at all because you have already defined the user but you defined a user again at the second user`".user"`.mention, instead do it like this:

```js
**User:** <@${user.id}>
```

and at the second undefined which is the moderator who requested the ban `message.author.mention` the `message.author` is correct but the `.mention` isn't, so what you're going to do instead is:

```js
**Moderator:** <@${message.author.id}>
```

Comment: or if you don't want to mention them, just change the ".id" into ".username" and remove the <@......>